# picasso throw an exception: context == null

Tags: java, android, picasso

i use it load image into view at RecyclerView, but throws an exception : context == null, and its occured  when i got androidX. its working fine before i update;
thanks for helping ^.^

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: context == null
    at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.get(Picasso.java:681)
    at com.android.mytestdemo.presenter.NewsInfoViewHolder.setData(NewsInfoViewHolder.java:67)
    at com.android.mytestdemo.presenter.NewsInfoViewHolder.setData(NewsInfoViewHolder.java:14)
    at com.jude.easyrecyclerview.adapter.RecyclerArrayAdapter.OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerArrayAdapter.java:627)
    at com.jude.easyrecyclerview.adapter.RecyclerArrayAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerArrayAdapter.java:622)
    at com.jude.easyrecyclerview.adapter.RecyclerArrayAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerArrayAdapter.java:50)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
    at com.android.mytestdemo.adapter.NewsInfoAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NewsInfoAdapter.java:32)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
```

This is newsInfoAdapter:

```
public class NewsInfoAdapter extends RecyclerArrayAdapter {

private Context mContext;

public NewsInfoAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public BaseViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    return new NewsInfoViewHolder(parent,mContext);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull List payloads) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
    holder.itemView.setTag(position);

}
```

This is ViewHolder code :

```
public class NewsInfoViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder<NewsInfo> {

private Context mContext;

private ImageView imageView;
private TextView tvTitle;
private ImageView ivPlayAndPause;

private boolean isPlaying = false;

public NewsInfoViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, Context context) {
    super(parent, R.layout.easy_rv_item);

    this.mContext = context;

    imageView = $(R.id.news_img);
    ivPlayAndPause = $(R.id.iv_play);
    tvTitle = $(R.id.news_title);


    ivPlayAndPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (isPlaying){
                ivPlayAndPause.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_play_48dp));
                isPlaying = false;
            }else {
                ivPlayAndPause.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_pause_48dp));
                isPlaying = true;
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void setData(NewsInfo data) {
    super.setData(data);
    String picTo ;
    String pic ;

    if (data.getImgUrlPicTo() != null && !(data.getImgUrlPicTo().equals(""))){


        if (data.getImgUrlPicTo().contains("https:"))
            picTo = data.getImgUrlPicTo();
        else
            picTo = "https:" + data.getImgUrlPicTo();

        Picasso.get().load(picTo).fit().into(imageView);

    }else if (data.getImgUrlPic() != null && !(data.getImgUrlPic().equals(""))){

        if (data.getImgUrlPic().contains("https:"))
            pic = data.getImgUrlPic();
        else
            pic = "https:" + data.getImgUrlPic();


        Picasso.get().load(pic).fit().into(imageView);
    }

    tvTitle.setText(data.getTitle());

}
```

}

its working fine before i update to androidX.
thanks for help again ^.^

Comment: show your adapter code

Comment: @Joey post your try for adapter and calling adapter

Comment: please show us the `NewsInfoAdapter` and the `NewsInfoViewHolder`.

Comment: @Radesh  i posted, ^.^

Comment: @MartinZeitler I posted

Comment: @AndroidUser i posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on this issue on picasso's github [issues/1929](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1929)

You can't use `Picasso.get()` in view holder. Basically it's a bug and must be fixed but for now you can post Picasso in constructor of your adapter.

I use androidX too, but because i use [dagger](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2) to provide picasso . don't face with this problem

Comment: Actually, you can use `Picasso.get()`: you will need to initialize Picasso in application class ([sample](https://github.com/ozbek/picasso-viewholder)).

Comment: @ozbek If my project doesn't have a application class, can I initialize it in my "MainActivity"?

Comment: @ClassA no need to init in ApplicationClass just in case that you have some global setting for picasso

Comment: @Radesh What do you suggest I do then? Currently, I'm implementing Picasso in my `RecyclerView`'s `OnBingViewHolder`, like this - `Picasso.get().load(category.get(position).getImage()).noFade().tag("tag").resize(100, 100).centerCrop().networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder).into(holder.img, new Callback() {....`

Comment: @ClassA ok whats wrong? if you have error ask new question and tag me in comment i will answer

Comment: @Radesh I posted a question, here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56459099/picasso-context-null-issue

Comment: @Radesh I tried tagging you in the comments of that question, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

**Put below code in your Application class**

```
public class MainApplicationClass extends Application {
        
          @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                super.onCreate();
        
              // You need to add the below code:
               Picasso.setSingletonInstance(new Picasso.Builder(this).build());
             }
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

Please put the below code in Application class. If Android version is 7.0 over, you need to add the below code.

```
Picasso.setSingletonInstance(new Picasso.Builder(this).build());
```

Answer (score 2):

**Initialize Singleton Instance from version 2.71828 in Picasso library**

```
 //lib
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'


private static boolean initializedPicasso = false;

public static void initPicasso(Context context) {
    Log.i("TAG", "initializedPicasso:" + initializedPicasso);
    if (initializedPicasso) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        Picasso.setSingletonInstance(new Picasso.Builder(context).build());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error:" + e.toString());
    }

    initializedPicasso = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put the below code block inside your **setUp()** method of **Test class**.

```
 @Before
fun setUp() {
    mockkStatic(Picasso::class)
    val picassoMock = mockkClass(Picasso::class, relaxed = true)
    coEvery {
        Picasso.get()
    } returns picassoMock
}
```