# Picasso context==null issue

Tags: java, android, picasso

I'm getting the following crash in crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: context == null
   at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.get(Picasso.java:681)
   at com.package.name.Recycler.RecyclerVideoAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerVideoAdapter.java:435)
```

`RecyclerVideoAdapter.java:435` is referring to:

```
Picasso.get().load(category.get(position).getImage()).noFade().tag("tag").resize(100, 100).centerCrop().networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder).into(holder.img, new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        //Success
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {
        Picasso.get().load(category.get(position).getImage()).noFade().resize(100, 100).centerCrop().memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder).into(holder.img);
    }
});
```

The above is being called inside my `onBindViewHolder`

---

I have seen this issue being posted [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1929), but I can't find a solution to this.

I think it's also worth mentioning that this issue is intermitted.

---

Question:

Has anyone experience this issue and what did you do to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize your Picasso's singleton instance. Put this code in your Application class onCreate() method:

```
Picasso.setSingletonInstance(
                new Picasso.Builder(this)
                        // additional settings
                        .build());
```

Comment: I don't have an application class, please see my comments in this answer asked eirlier today - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53350886/8199772

Comment: Can you please provide me with a suggestion? I asked on that answer if I can initialize `Picasso` inside my "MainActivity".

Comment: @ClassA I am not sure it's a good idea to initialize the singletone in the activity class because you activity can be recreated due to configuration change or something else. But you can create your application class and register it in the manifest. Then put the code above in onCreate methond in your application class so you'll be sure it will be initialized just once

Comment: Since I can't test if it is working, I will accept your answer and check if I still get this crash after updating. Thank you.